# How can I write mathematics model in beamer LaTex

Tags: latex

How to write math models in LaTex. 
I tried this code:

```
\begin{frame} 
\frametitle{Random Walk}
E(Rj(j,t+1) | φ_t )=(Rj(j,t+1) )    // this model I copy from a papper
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Do you not know LaTeX, or `beamer`, or both?

Comment: I wasn't able to do the code in LaTex. I belive that Beamer is the template.

Comment: [`beamer`](//ctan.org/pkg/beamer) is a *class* in LaTeX. It's still unclear to me what you want to do? Are you creating a presentation and you want to use LaTeX's `beamer` to write the presentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enclose mathematics type inside dollar signs `$ ... $` for inline mathematics or for a block element `\[ ... \]`. Also φ should be typeset with `\phi`. And if you want the `E` to be bold you can use `\mathbf{E}`. Similarly if you want `Rj` to be typeset upright and next to each other instead of looking like variables multiplied, use `\mathrm{Rj}` or define your own symbol at the start of the document.

LaTeX is it's own language, and there's an entire Stack site dedicated to TeX and its variants: https://tex.stackexchange.com/

Since you're new it might be good to read up on a tutorial or two. There are a ton of resources online but I like the online LaTeX compiler ShareLaTeX and they've got a [good set of tutorials covering the basics](https://www.sharelatex.com/blog/latex-guides/beginners-tutorial.html). I also think [this](http://www.andy-roberts.net/writing/latex) is a great start to learning the ins and outs of LaTeX.